# Manipulate an element created by external JS

Tags: jquery

So on my page I have a script tag that loads an external JS file. This then renders a form with a button (class is 'btn') and has text that says 'Add your story'. On page load once the form is rendered I would like to change the text to something else.

```
    $('.buttons').on('click', 'button', function(){
    // do something here
    });
```

I used something like this in the past but relies on an 'click' event but now I need a 'load' event? Any help please. Thanks.

Comment: change text in jquery ready function that's enough !
`$(function(){   /* code to change text button */ });`

Comment: if you load the external JS file via jQuery there is a completion callback in the load function, why don't you use that for your code?